How to dynamically move previous last dates period while simultaneously giving user functionality to choose custom dates from same slicer in Power BI?
I have one table named Orders, in which I have Order Date as a column. I was to create a date range slicer for orders made so that slicer will automatically update to new dates/data whenever it will come and simultaneously giving user the functionality to choose manual date range from that slicer only.
I am able to create dynamic date slicer as below:
Last 12 monthes period = IF(
    Orders[Order Date] >= MAX(Orders[Order Date]) - 365 && Orders[Order Date] <= MAX(Orders[Order Date]),
    Orders[Order Date],BLANK()
)

But it is restricting the user from selecting the custom dates.
I am using very simple visulas:

How can I achieve this please suggest some solutions.
Any help is really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

maybe you can try
Measure = if(max('Table'[Date])<=CALCULATE(max('Table'[Date]),all('Table'))-365,0,1)

and add this measure to visual filter and set to 1


Hi @Ryan, I tried it but it is not allowing me to select any dates other than 1 year and I want to have two functionality :

To show automatically updating latest one year dates by default.
Also give functionality to change the dates as per user requirement and not restricting to one year only.


I think your two requirements conflicts. The second one is out of the scope of first one. Let' see if anyone else can have better solution for this.
